# When to use Class methods over Activities?

Tags: android, design-patterns

I'm getting introduced to Android programming and want to understand Activities a bit more (I'm coming in with basic-advanced java knowledge, basic knowledge in GUIs).

I currently assume that all methods will be contained in their respective activity, or in some helper class--whose methods wouldn't be shown to the user, (unless an activity used it), but whose methods could perhaps be used in multiple activities.

1. Are these assumptions correct?
2. When are helper classes even required?
3. Any good online resources regarding (specifically) classes vs activity use cases?
4. Any examples of a fairly simple, complete APK where I could look through and dissect the code, including XML?  Hopefully something I could just import into Android Studio.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, the methods are either in the activity or in other classes, but since there is no other places for java code to be, could you clarify this question better?
2. To reduce the complexity of Activitys. If you have very little logic, it is perfectly fine, to have all the code in the activity. But as soon as the count of lines rise, you may run into problems like readability, testability and things like that. 
   But you should at least put code, that you use in different Activitys, into separate classes.
3. A good example would be something like M(odel)V(iew)P(resenter), where the goal is, to separate the View (Setup Buttons, Textview etc.), the presenter (Connection the loginbutton to the loginservice while showing a loginview) and the model (The actual implementation of the loginservice).
4. Google itself offers some examples for a clean [architecture](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture) and a simple example for [MVP](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvp/).

Comment: 3.  This is now my root question.  An example helps, are there any other resources I should look for?  (Searching for "Activity vs. Classes" etc.?)


1. The main reason I asked this is because I have this notion of Activities≈GUI, but I'm getting rid of that notion.  In Android, the Activities themselves include their own methods and variables.

2.  I guess the question then becomes, "How complex do I want my Activities to be?  What is "proper"?"  I'll search for more info to read into it.

4.  Upon first look, that first link of clean architecture is going to be a huge help, thanks!

Comment: Anyways, thanks for the response. It helps an absolute ton!

Answer (score 0):

Try android programming the big nerd ranch guide , its very useful for beginners 
And try youtube channel "wiseass"
He has good videos on mvp architecture